# Yii. Как задать новый путь для модели backend?

Tags: php, mvc, yii2

Проблема в том, что недавно перенес сайт на хостинг. Тех. поддержка с помощью симлинков помогла запустить его.

Теперь при открытии контроллера в backend части, мне выпадает ошибка, что не находится модель. Хотя она лежит в папке backend/models/. По всей видимости открывает frontend папку моделей и ищет там. Как мне быть, друзья?

Изменение namespace в контроллере backend/controllers/CallbackController/ не помогает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для ответа на ваш вопрос мало данных. Возможно проблема в файле autoload.php который создает composer.

Comment: А use прописан в CallbackController для CallbackSearch модели? Как он выглядит? И какой у этих двух классов namespace?

Comment: @white-imp use прописан: `use app\models\CallbackSearch;`

Пробовал app заменить на backend, результат тот же самый - плачевный.

Comment: CallbackController: `namespace app\controllers;`
callbackSearch: `namespace app\models;`

Comment: Может быть дело в изменении urlManager файла main.php? Его меняли мне, чтобы админскую панель через /admin открывать.

Comment: @Benlamin, это же Advanced Yii2 template? Если так, то неймспейсы в корне не верные. Подтверди и я сейчас напишу как должно быть.

Comment: Не переносили ли вы проект с винды, где у вас не в том регистре имя файла?

Comment: @Etki  я с MacOS переносил, нашел проблему. Оказывается, она совершенно в другом. 

При переносе с одного домена на другой, сохранился путь /home/w/websho/summit.today/backend/controllers/CallbackController.php 

Но у меня сейчас другой путь. Пробую исправить проблему сию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Yii2 advanced template, учитывая структуру приложения, namespace'ы должны выглядеть так:

```
CallbackController: namespace backend\controllers;
CallbackSearch: namespace backend\models;
```

Соответственно в CallbackController прописываем для использования модели CallbackSearch:

```
use backend\models\CallbackSearch;
```

UPD: 'app' в неймспейсах не должно быть в advanced template. Такое есть только в basic template. Вместо этого нужно писать 'backend', 'frontend' или 'common'. Если по каким-то неизвестным или неучтенным причинам должно работать c "app", то попробуй писать неймспейсы и юзы как "app\backend...".

Вот живой пример: [github Yii2 advanced backend\SiteController](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/backend/controllers/SiteController.php)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я представляю себе общую картину! Но результат остался прежним, фатальная ошибка: `Class 'app\models\CallbackSearch' not found`

Comment: В CallbackController про "app" ни слова нет.

Comment: @BenjaminButton, так а 'use backend\models\CallbackSearch;' прописано перед классом контроллера?

Comment: Да, конечно. PHPStorm также позволяет перейти в этот файл из этой строчки use.

Comment: @BenjaminButton, задампи переменную из 35й строки $searchModel и помести результат дампа в описание вопроса.

Comment: @BenjaminButton, и еще произведи поиск через контекстное меню в дереве проекта "Find in path" по всему каталогу проекта и найди где еще эта модель используется как 'app\models\SearchModel'. Если ты поменял неймспейсы и юзы, то возможно где-то что-то осталось, что перебивает использование правильного пути к модели.